# Angularjs Show Data on select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am developing a website using Angularjs and I am a beginner.
So I have a combo box. After selecting an option it calls a method and should load values in a Scope variable and update it.
Here is my code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl',  function ($scope, $http) {


    $scope.castVals = {};

    $http.get("http://localhost:8083/project/php/get_recipies.php")
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.recipies = response.records;
        $scope.selectedItem = null;

    });

    $scope.selectedItemChanged = function (val) {

        $http.get("http://localhost:8083/project/php/get_cast_param.php?v="+val)
                    .success(function (response) {
                        $scope.castVals = response;

         });

    };

});
```

And HTML Part

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<table ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left; padding-left:12px;">
                Select A Value
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="soflow" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="selectedItemChanged(rec.Rezept_Nr)">
                    <option ng-repeat="rec in recipies" value="{{rec.Rezept_Nr}}">{{rec.Rezept_Bez}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gesamtweg des Gießkolbens</td>
            <td >
                <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" value="{{castVals.gesamtweg}}"> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Thanks
Ashraf

Comment: Is this a question or just a statement ?

Comment: Has response object **gesamtweg** key?

Comment: @P_W999 Question  @ Sivailango yes it has a response object called gesamtweg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass the selected value to the selectedItemChange method as is safer to get it on the controller from the scope variable.

```
  <select id="soflow" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="selectedItemChanged()">
                    <option ng-repeat="rec in recipies" value="{{rec.Rezept_Nr}}">{{rec.Rezept_Bez}}</option>
                </select>
```

//Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl',  function ($scope, $http) {


$scope.castVals = {};
$scope.selectedItem;

$http.get("http://localhost:8083/project/php/get_recipies.php")
.success(function (response) {
    $scope.recipies = response.records;
    $scope.selectedItem = null;

});

$scope.selectedItemChanged = function () {

    $http.get("http://localhost:8083/project/php/get_cast_param.php?v="+ $scope.selectedItem)
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.castVals = response;

     });

};

});
```